# My Ether Wallet

Tags: transactions

I have been trying for days to get into this wallet. When I enter the website they tell me to go to Metamask who in turn tells me to go to Digibit. All I am trying to do is get my ether out of my ether wallet and transfer it to Blockchain wallet.
Can someone help me. This is driving me nuts. I have a wallet address that shows up on Etherscan with the total amount of ether and I have an address of where I want to send it.
Richard

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.myetherwallet.com, click "Send Ether & Tokens", enter your private key and then fill the form in order to send ether.

I don't get why they tell you to go to metamask. If you get any errors, make a screenshot and post it here.